# global hotkeys in xfce

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, xfce

I noticed in xfce, global hotkeys don't seem to work. Such as:

- multimedia buttons (play/pause/volum up/down/mute, etc)
- gnome-do not appearing when hitting the specified key (`<alt>space` in my case).

Is this a feature of xfce that can't be worked around? or is there a way to "fix" it?

PS: for gnome-do I worked around it by binding `<alt>space` to gnome-do from the keyboard settings page. `Xfce Settings Manager > Keyboard > Application shortcuts`

#### Update

To clarify, I already bound the volume up/down/mute to inc/dec/mute volume using aumix and a special script for mute which I found on ubuntu forums.

I noticed that the play/pause button works *only* when the media player has the focus; it doesn't work as a global hotkey. If I remember correctly, in Gnome, the media players respond to play/pause regardless of where the focus is; so it's either an Xfce issue or some sort of service/daemon is missing.

Answer (score 1):

At least on the two distributions (Xubuntu, Arch) that I've used, none of the hotkeys were defined by default.

For the multimedia keys I recommend using aumix as listed on [this page](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7049).

Comment: I already did that for volume up/down, even found a script for mute. What bugged me today was that play/pause only works *inside* a media player, not as a global key